# How to Prevent Others From Using My PHP Script?

Tags: php, image, security

I have php script that process and render (output) image. I use my PHP script in HTML like this:

```
<img src="MyScript.php?Parm1=Value1&Parm2=Value2">
```

The problem is I have limited bandwidth on my server and I don't want others use my script. But as anyone can see that from HTML source and use and that would be a issue to my sever.

Is there any way to prevent others from using it? For example, script will only run from my local sever?

Comment: Configure your server to not serve/process the script when the source IP != localhost (::1).

Comment: You need to take account of 1 fact: WORLD has access to your HTML. ONLY YOU have access of what happens INSIDE your server. USE this  fact for protection.

Comment: You have a few options. One of which and if you're NOT on `nginx`, can use `.htaccess` to protect it. You can use PHP to password protect it, or you can place it outside of the publicly accessed folders. Those, are but a few methods.

Answer (score 4):

### HTTP referer

> [HTTP referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) is an HTTP header
>   field that identifies the address of the webpage (i.e. the URI or IRI)
>   that linked to the resource being requested. By checking the referer,
>   the new webpage can see where the request originated.

This is typically used as basic protection against [hot-linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_linking). It can be circumvented by faking HTTP referer header, but in 99% of the cases circumventing that is more fuss than it's worth to the leechers.

In PHP you can access that header via `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Check if the URL is your domain and reject everything else.

You can also do that at Apache config or `.htaccess` level using RewriteEngine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.yourdomain.com/.*
RewriteRule .*\.php - [NC,F]
```

### Cookies

Store random, unique value and timestamp in session. Generate cookie with the random value. Set this as a cookie while generating your HTML. When you receive request to your image generator script do following:

1. is cookie there? if not reject request
2. do cookie value match one of these stored in session? if not, reject
3. is timestamp for that value fresher than X seconds? if not, reject

Again, this can be to some extent circumvented, but it's significantly harder and will require making at least one request to your legitimate HTML.

Both of these techniques combined would take care of virtually any leechers you could encounter.

Comment: nice! thanks.. 
sir, i am working on wamp server (for local development and testing) but i think wamp don't have $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']? any idea?